# Nginx SNI wildcard proxy

Tags: nginx

Потребовалось реализовать специализированный кейс: есть некоторый балансировщик, который должен принимать и перенаправлять произвольные HTTP и HTTPS-запросы, не имея на руках ни сертификатов, ни заранее известных адресов, на которые нужно перенаправлять запросы. Технически это реализуемо с помощью SNI (получить server name -> перенаправить tcp-поток на него), но все примеры в интернете сводятся к перенаправлению на заранее известный адрес, и конфигурация с предустановленными адресами уже начала разбухать.

Можно ли сконфигурировать nginx таким образом, чтобы он извлекал FQDN из SNI, резолвил его (в локальном DNS прописаны конечные адреса), и перенаправлял TCP-поток на полученный IP?

Фактически требуется сделать банальный

```
server {
    listen 80;
    proxy_pass $host;
}
```

Но с учетом того, что трафик идет в зашифрованном виде на 443, и host можно извлечь только из SNI.